# Can we install ROS on Red Hat Linux

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am planning to buy a  workstation with Red Hat Linux OS. Can we install ROS on it?? Also can we install RViz on Red Hat Linux??
Please can someone answer this asap.

Regards
Sudeep

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262415/can-we-install-ros-on-red-hat-linux/) by [Sudeepverma](https://answers.ros.org/users/30498/sudeepverma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-05-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update (2020-03-12): there appears to be work ongoing to add RHEL/Fedora support to `ros_buildfarm` et al. See [the list of merged PRs](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/pulls?q=is%3Apr+rpm+is%3Aclosed).

---

I don't think anyone can guarantee that it'll work, but it should be possible to do a source build. I'm not sure whether the Fedora RPMs that get build are usable on a RHEL system.

See #q216929 and #q119716 for related questions. At least the first one was successful in installing the core packages.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudeepverma](https://answers.ros.org/users/30498/sudeepverma/) on 2017-05-24**:
Thanks @Gvdhoorn for quick reply. I also thinking of taking a Windows 10 Machine and make it dual booting with Ubunto 16.04 LTS. Please let me know if this is right approach  to Install ROS and RViz.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-25**:
16.04 will definitely work, as it's a supported distribution.

**Comment by [lxg](https://answers.ros.org/users/37572/lxg/) on 2020-03-12**:
@sudeepvernma. that definitely works. am using it on my windows 10 machine too.